# Chrome extension authorize users using Google Oauth

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I want to have a popup iframe like buffer chrome extension to authorize google users. I have been looking for similar solution like this. But so far I can't find a good solution yet. However, I found an example to use Google identity to authorize google users for my chrome extension.

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken()
```

Is this a right approach?

What I am looking is something similar to this image for google authorization.

[image]

Comment: thats the right approach for oauth providers. have you tried it?  the only drawback for using with google scopes is that the user must be signed into chrome.

Comment: I can't find any good example using this chrome.identity for google oauth. Do you know any?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for Google accounts, `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()` is the way to go.  For other accounts, there is `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()`.

These are both documented on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity, and there is some example code at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity